# Preserve Folder Hierarchy in IOS for html files

Tags: ios, html, ipad, uiwebview, nsurl

I am trying to include a folder structure into my xcode project that contains html, css, js and images like below:

```
htmlcontent
    html
       test.html
    css
       test.css
    js
       test.js
```

I copied the folder and its subfolder to xcode and i can see the heirachy there but when i do the following:

```
NSString *pathToFile = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"test" ofType:@"html"];
NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:pathToFile isDirectory:NO];
[_webView loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url]];
```

it prints:

```
/Users/scoota/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/6.0/Applications/8AAC5870-DF24-49BB-BCB8-598C8C0A7C9A/TestApp.app/test.html
```

Is there a way to preserve the hierachy? The reason i ask is my html file has references to the css like so:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="htmlcontent/test.css" media="screen, projector" />
```

As a result the css is not loaded. If I change it to the following:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="test.css" media="screen, projector" />
```

it loads.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you add files to your Xcode project, make sure you select "make folder references" instead of "make groups for folders"

However, shouldn't that be ,,/css/test.css ?

Comment: Thanks that seemed to work. However, in my html file i have ../css/test.css and it isnt found. Does the relative pathing with .. work with IOS?

Comment: You need to make sure that you set the base URL of your web view (for example, in the function `loadHTMLString:baseURL:`).  It should be the folder that your HTML is in.